# how to get infos from jenkins pipeline downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have one pipeline jobA to trigger another pipeline jobB using code like:
steps.build jobB xxx

Here is the problem:
In jobB, I did some check and get the check state, it should be pass or fail. This state is not jobB's job state.
I'd like to get this state in jobA.
Anyway to get the state info from downstream jobs.

I don't want to write the state to a file in jobB and read it out in jobA, I just want to simply check the state using variable

Comment: I tried with this method, define an env value in jobA, as env.checkState="paas", then in jobB, check the env.checkState info, it shows null, seems the env value defined in jobA can't be get in jobB.

Comment: seems not way to do that, at last I use the write file method, write a file in downstream job and read it in the upstream job